# setting deployment target for iPhone app

Tags: iphone

i tested my application by setting deployment target to 3.0 on iPhone device with 4.3.2 version and my iPhone app was running smoothly so my question is that do i still need to test my app on iPhone device with lower version like 3.0 before submitting it to app store.
Thanks in advance for your any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: if you call any API that was introduced after iOS 3.0, it will crash.  The only way to be sure is to test on an actual 3.0 device.

Comment: Thanku Daniel Dickison for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definitely should test your application on a device with iOS3 to ensure that everything is working.

Setting the deployment target to iOS3 only ensure linking. **Do not forget** that iOS3 has *not only* different APIs, *but also* differents behaviors for ***same components***, even **with same code**.

And behaviors can even differs from Simulator to Device!

Comment: Thanku vincent for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, but... The stackoverflow way to thank someone for an answer is to **accept and/or vote** the answer... :) see previous comment mentionning this > http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work